# Ionic 3 input box is not clickable on first load

Tags: android, ionic-framework, input, ionic3

I'm working on a Ionic 3 project (v3.9.3). I got an input box as simple as this:

```
<ion-content>
      <ion-input  type="text"  name="text" ></ion-input>
</ion-content>
```

On Chrome debug it works fine. But on Android phone (v9.0) When the page with the input box loads the first time, if I click on the input box, nothing happens, the keyboard does not show up!  But if I click on the empty space then click the input box again, the keyboard shows up and I'm able to input text. I change another Android phone got the same problem.

The only thing I notice on one of the phone when I click on the dead input box is that the adb says "WebView autofill is disabled because webview isn't created with activity context.".

Does anybody know how to solve this? Is it related to the Webview autofill? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Remove "ion-content" tag from your html, and now it should work.